# Проблема с аутентификацией

Tags: php, html, css

Зарегистрировался, потом этими данными захожу, зашел не проблем, а потом когда перехожу для просмотра заказа, автоматически выходить.
Да мой русский дает о себя знать.

Вот картинки

1 Картинка Зарегистрировался но не вошел в систему.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2 Картинка вошел систему по своим логином и паролем.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
3 Картинка перехожу в заказы, тут и фокус, как то выходить из системы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
4 Картинка показываю что не могу сделать заказ. Я уже не в системе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на файлы тут [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85-vnJkulLoTlJtZnFoZHY4R2M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: нужно куки/сессию сохранять

Answer (score 3):

Ну во первых у вас сессия не стартует так как вы ее стартуете после того как уже заголовки были отправлены,прописывайте ее в самом начале файла!

Comment: А вам по ссылке код доступна

Comment: Я сделал так как в книге написано http://window.edu.ru/resource/937/79937/files/ECnew.pdf

Comment: Ну я не буду сейчас качать ваши файлы,я просто пояснил вам что нужно сделать,стартуйте сессию в самом начале файла

Comment: По любому выходить

Comment: Да в каждом файле в начале должно быть session_start();

Comment: решили ли вы проблему? если да - то отметьте галочкой "вопрос решен"

Answer (score 0):

ВНАЧАЛЕ КАЖДОГО СКРИПТА ДОЛЖНА БЫТЬ СТРОКА.

```
session_start();
```

А у вас сессия по условию стартует. я так понял из вашего скриншота.

И еще возможно в браузере отключены куки?

Answer (score 0):

1. session_start();  //запускайте сессию
2. если заполнены поля логина и пароля то сохраните их в сессии $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];... и т.д. для пароля.
3. потом проверяете базу, есть такой логин, если есть то проверяете введенный пароль с паролем который лежит на базе.
4. если все условии вернут true, тогда создайте сессию типа $_SESSION['auth'] = 1;
5. и в начале каждой страницы стартуйте сессию и проверяйте существует ли $_SESSION['auth'] и равен ли он на 1.
6. если пункт 5 вернет true то покажите то что должен видеть зареганный пользователь а не то покажите инфу для гостья.
   это легкий способ для работы с сессией, если будет интересно с куки, то радостью поможем задавайте вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?   
      $title="Авторизация"; 
      $color="#aaaaff"; 

      $pass=$_POST["pass"]; 
      $login=$_POST["login"]; 

      include("connect.phtml");  

      $strSQL1="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE login='".$login."' AND pass='".$pass."'"; 
      $result1=mysql_query($strSQL1) or die("Не могу выполнить запрос!"); 

      // пользователь с таким логином и паролем найдем ? 
      if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))  
      {   
         $start=session_start();    // начинаем сессию 
         // Создадим сеансовую переменную для ФИО покупателя  
         session_register("log");  
         $_SESSION["log"]=$row["fam"]." ".$row["im"]; 
         // Создадим сеансовую переменную для ID покупателя 
         session_register("id");  
         $_SESSION["id"]=$row["id_cust"]; 
         $message="<tr><td bgcolor='#66cc66' align='center'> 
                   <b>Вы успешно авторизованы</b></td></tr>"; 
         $success=true; 
      } 
      else 
      { 
         $message="<tr><td bgcolor='#ff9999' align='center'> 
            <b>Таких логина/ пароля не существует!!!</b></td></tr>"; 
      } 

      mysql_close(); 

      if($success) 
      { 
         include ("cabinet.phtml"); 
      } 
      else 
      {
         include("header.phtml"); 
         print $message; 
         include("footer.phtml"); 
      } 
  ?>
```

Вот здесь, когда запуская она ругается

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at D:\home\site.ru\www\auto.phtml:1) in D:\home\site.ru\www\auto.phtml on line 1

Deprecated: Function session_register() is deprecated in D:\home\site.ru\www\auto.phtml on line 18

Deprecated: Function session_register() is deprecated in D:\home\site.ru\www\auto.phtml on line 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы не хотите использовать фреймворки, имеется в виду один из популярных, - то есть решение для нативного программирования на РНР.
Библиотека [PHPAuth](https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth) наделена разного рода возможностями от авторизации до восстановления пароля по Email и локализации сообщений.

В фреймворках есть уже встроенные компоненты авторизации.

А в Вашем случае - сессия не стартует там, где надо и заголовки описаны после отдаи контента, что делать нельзя.